# jquery datatable get json data from ajax

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to build a datatable from the json data I am getting on the server

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {

        "ajax": "/analyze/List",
        "columns": [
        { responsedata: "Name" },
        { responsedata: "Total" },
        { responsedata: "Passed" },
        { responsedata: "Failed" }]  

        } );
    } );
```

Didn't work.Is that not how it's supposed to be done ? .

Here's the json data format on server-

```
{"responseCode":0,"responseData":[{"Name":"Rocky","Total":39,"Passed":35,"Failed":4}]}
```

Also, I'm an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Could someone help ? I'm a noob in this.

Comment: Check out the "Ajax" tab on the example, I think your JSON needs to be formatted differently: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: yeah, looks like i'll have to change the format and try .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yu are doing it a little bit backwards. Use the `dataSrc` attribute to instruct dataTables that the rows is hold by the `responseData` property, and refer to each field via the `data` attribute, not `responseData` :

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '/analyze/List',
        dataSrc: 'responseData'
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "Name" }, 
      { data: "Total" }, 
      { data: "Passed" },
      { data: "Failed" }
    ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2qycjwaz/**